# Have an ImageView with same width and height in ConstraintLayout

Tags: imageview, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

How can we make ImageView width and height equal to width of parent ConstraintLayout? So it displays a full width square ImageView.

Generally how can one set HEIGHT of some widget equal to WIDTH of other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following layout will place a square blue image in the center of the parent `ConstraintLayout`. The key piece is `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) for details.

> You can also define one dimension of a widget as a ratio of the other one. In order to do that, you need to have at least one constrained dimension be set to 0dp (i.e., MATCH_CONSTRAINT), and set the attribute layout_constraintDimensionRatio to a given ratio.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cheticamp's answer is great. Here is an answer for AndroidX.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:androidx="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            androidx:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            androidx:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            androidx:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            androidx:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            androidx:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```